# Pdf Navigation from Table of contents

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, navigation

I am working on a flutter app which generates PDF files in flutter using pdf library.I need to create a pdf file which has a table of contents. They should be linked with the actual content and should navigate to their respective pages when clicked on it. I couldn't find any documentation online for doing this using the pdf library. The PDF is going to be written to a file so PDF Viewers in flutter are not useful for me either. Can someone please help me out

can we use html code with dart like <a tag or something for internal navigation in PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Anchor and Link widgets from `pdf/widgets.dart` for internal navigation inside the generated PDF.
Just create an `Anchor` on the page to which you want to navigate to. You need to provide a `name` parameter for it and it should be unique.

```
Anchor(name:'my_anchor', child: any_child_widget);
```

You can now refer to that anchor from another page using `Link` widget.

```
Link(destination:'my_anchor',child: any_child_widget);
```

You can enclose any child within the `Anchor` and `Link` widget.